# istio-operator image is no longer available in the public istio-release registry on GCR

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, docker-registry, google-container-registry

We have recently come across an issue on one of our cluster pods, which caused an outage on our application and impacted our customers.

Here is the thing: We were able to pull the `gke.gcr.io/istio/operator:1.6.3` image from GCR, though, it started failing overnight.
Finally, we noticed that this image is no longer available in the public [istio-release registry, on gcr.io](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/istio-release), causing a `ImagePullBackoff` failure. However, we are still able to find it on [docker.io](https://hub.docker.com/layers/istio/operator/1.6.5/images/sha256-85dd115c75c6068aca1c67bee2d95e027152bcc6444fbeef67506959e3ea9fde?context=explore).

Having said that, we're sticking with the solution approach of pulling the image from `docker.io/istio/operator:1.6.3`, which is a pretty straightforward one for now. Nevertheless, we're still skeptical and wondering why this image has suddenly vanished from gcr.io.

Has anyone been facing something similar?

Best regards.

Comment: I've never faced this issue, and I can't found anything about. But i should suggest you to keep the most critical images in a internal register. Although it is oficial registry, you don't have control over the images and versions. Keeping the images on your side you can prevent incidents like that. I will try to looking for some news about that fact.

Answer (score 1):

I did some reasearch but I can't find anything related.

As I mentioned in comments, I strongly suggest you keep all critical images in a private container registry. Using this approach you can avoid incidents like that, and earn some extra control upon the images, such as: **versioning**, the **security** etc.

There are many guides on the internet to setup your own managed private container registry like [Nexus](https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-3-docker-images), if you want to use as a service, you can try [Gooogle Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs).

Keep in mind that when you are working in a critical environment, you need to try minize the variables to keep your service as resilient as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a small downtime with one of our services deployed to the GKE and noticed istio-operator was listed with a red warning.

The log was:

> Back-off pulling image "gke.gcr.io/istio/operator:1.6.4": ImagePullBackOff

Since istio-operator is a workload GKE manages I was hesitant but the downtime repeated couple of times for couple of minutes so I also edited the service yaml and update the image with docker.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26863815)

Comment: I meant to add as a comment but since I lack the reputation to comment I was unable to. But I also want to include myself since this is clearly not an isolated issue. Sorry if my input mislead anyone.